# What is the common expression saying that a person has played or gone out so long that it makes you feel unhappy?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A mom let her child to play with friends but the child must get home on time. However, the child plays for a very very long time and she/he only gets home much later than the time her mom expects. The mom gets upset for that.

What is the common expression saying that a person has played or gone out so long that it makes you feel unhappy?

Comment: I should think a parent would be both angry (at the disobedience) and worried (what if there has been an accident?) if their child doesn't come home when they promised to.

Comment: [let her child play, not "to play//let does not take to]. Your question is not clear but: "You didn't come home on time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's not overcomplicate this.  The best word is the simple one, "late".

> Why were you so late, don't you think your father and I have been worrying about you?

If someone is late, that means they arrive after they are expected.  If you have the context (the relationship between mother and child) it is sufficient to say "late" and infer that the mother was upset.